# Is it possible to call getter and setter properties with parameters in Python?

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter

Probably this can't be done the way I would like. I was making a `class Temperature` in python.

I would like to set a property called `temperature` and set or retrieve its value on different scales like Kevin, Celsius or Fahrenheit.

**Set temperature:**

```
T = Temperature() 
T.temperature = 20                # Set temperature to 20ºC
T.temperature('Fahrenheit') = 68  # Set temperature to 68ºF
T.temperature('Kelvin') = 305     # Set temperature to 305K
```

**Get temperature:**

```
t = T.temperature                 # retrieves temperature in Celsius
t = T.temperature('Fahrenheit')   # retrieves temperature in Fahrenheit
t = T.temperature('Kelvin')       # retrieves temperature in Kelvin
```

I have this code. Firstly I tried to use `@property` decorator but it was not working. Then I decided to move to traditional syntax using `x=property(x_get, x_set)`

```python
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self, temperature:float = 0, scale:str = "Celsius"):
        # All temperatures will be stored as KELVIN
        self._temperature = None
        self.set_temperature(temperature, scale)

    def get_temperature(self, scale: str = "Celsius"):
        converter = {
            "Celsius": self._temperature - 273.15,
            "Fahrenheit": ((self._temperature - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32,
            "Kelvin": self._temperature
        }
        value = converter.get(scale)

        return value

    def set_temperature(self, value: float, scale: str = "Celsius"):
        converter = {
            "Celsius": value + 273.15,
            "Fahrenheit": (value - 32) / 1.8 + 273.15,
            "Kelvin": value
        }

        self._temperature = converter.get(scale)

        if self._temperature < 0 :
            self._temperature = None
            raise ValueError("Temperature below 0 Kelvin is not possible")

    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)
```

But I cannot use the proposed syntax; although using traditional syntax seems to be a good approach.

It works when calling to property `temperature` without any parameters or directly to get and set methods with parameters:

```
>>> T = Temperature(20) # Initialize
>>> T.temperature       # Getter
20.0

>>> T.temperature=30    # Setter
>>> T.temperature       # Getter
30.0
```

It works if I call directly to `get_temperature` or `set_temperature`

```
>>> T.get_temperature("Fahrenheit")
86.0
```

But if I call to getter or setter property with parameter it raises an error:

```
T.temperature("Fahrenheit")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Or

```
T.temperature("Kelvin") = 301.15
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call


T.temperature = 68, 'Fahrenheit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 19, in set_temperature
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think getters and setters are necessary, nor pythonic... By using getters and setters you are making attributes of a class private to protect them from other codes. The pythonic way of providing this protection is actually by introducing the attributes publicly.

to design a class in a psuedo-java way you could do the following:

```
class temperature:

    def __init__(self.temp):
        self.__temp = temp
    
    def get_temp(self): 
        return self.__temp
   
    def set_temp(self, temp):
        self.__temp = temp
```

and to access the data you would do the below

```
>>>temp1 = temperature(135)
>>>temp1.set_temp(14)
>>>temp1.get_temp()
14
```

however, a more pythonic way to design this class would be without the getter and setter and using a public attribute.

```
class temperature: 

    def __init__(self, temp): 
        self.temp = temp
```

Now you can just access the same attributes without having to use getters or setters

```
>>>temp1 = temperature(14)
>>>temp1.temp
14
```

Even though data is not necessarily encapsulated in this way ... it doesn't really need to be.

I realize that this doesn't address your concern with the three temperature scales but this can easily be accounted for by specifying the input temperature to a certain unit and then using conversion etc....

**EDIT**

On comment from @Carlo

The pythonic temperature class could be done below, assuming you specify an input temperature unit of kelvin, otherwise this class would need to be expanded to included farenheit and celsius input temperatures

```
class temperature():

    def __init__(self, temp, unit):
        self.temp = temp
        self.unit = unit

        if self.unit == 'K':
            self.temp_k = self.temp
            self.temp_c = self.temp_k + 273
            self.temp_f = (self.temp_k + 273)*(9/5)+32
        else:
            raise TypeError("only kelvin accepted as input temperature")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    temp1 = temperature(14, 'K')
    temp2 = temperature(14, 'C')  # will raise error
```

Accessing the temperature values for the temp1 object then simply becomes

```
>>> temp1.temp_k
14
>>> temp1.temp_c
287
>>> temp1.temp_f
548.6
```

Comment: Nice! I give you a tip to improve it, maybe you can create two separate setter/getter, one with the temperature and another one with the conversion type. You have to manage the initialization of the type conversion and work with it.

Comment: I would like to implement the different temperature scales. And an easy way to set or retrieve it in a single line code. Preferably with properties although I guess that I finally will use methods

Comment: The above class uses the init method only to establish the converted values and no additional methods for conversion. You can "get" the values of different temp units based on your initial temperature input, and if you want to use different input temp values just include those conditions in an additional set of if statements.

Comment: I appreciate your answers and comments. I will go with a property "temperature" and two methods "get_temperature" and "set_temperature" for those values not working with default scale.